# constrainedWidth/constrainedHeight in Jetpack Compose with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-jetpack-compose

How to set constrained width/height in Compose?

```
Text("Test", Modifier.constrainAs(text) {
    linkTo(
        start = parent.start,
        top = button.bottom,
        end = parent.end,
        bottom = parent.bottom,
        topMargin = 16.dp,
        horizontalBias = 0f
    )
    width = Dimension.wrapContent // this is default, can be removed
    // now I need to set constrainedWidth somehow like in XML app:layout_constrainedWidth 
})
```

`width = Dimension.preferredWrapContent` mb this one is equal to

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
```

?

Comment: as I tested seems correct

Answer (score 2):

using `Dimension.preferredWrapContent` worked for me:

```
modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(content) {
    width = Dimension.preferredWrapContent
    linkTo(
        start = parent.start,
        top = button.bottom,
        end = parent.end,
        bottom = parent.bottom,
        topMargin = 16.dp,
        horizontalBias = 0f
    )
}
```

for more info - https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/constraintlayout/compose/Dimension.Companion#preferredWrapContent()

Comment: Thanks for answer ! It save for me a long day !

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

In constraintLayout
Here are a sample of the various width and height patterns.

```kotlin
width = Dimension.matchParent
width = Dimension.value(23.dp)
width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
width = Dimension.fillToConstraints.atLeast(32.dp)
width = Dimension.fillToConstraints.atMost(125.dp)
width = Dimension.fillToConstraints.atLeast(32.dp).atMost(125.dp)
width = Dimension.fillToConstraints.atLeastWrapContent
width = Dimension.fillToConstraints.atLeastWrapContent.atMost(123.dp)
width = Dimension.fillToConstraints.atMostWrapContent
width = Dimension.fillToConstraints.atMostWrapContent.atLeast(23.dp)
width = Dimension.preferredWrapContent.atLeast(32.dp)
width = Dimension.preferredWrapContent.atMost(125.dp)
width = Dimension.preferredWrapContent.atLeast(32.dp).atMost(125.dp)
width = Dimension.preferredWrapContent.atLeastWrapContent
width = Dimension.preferredWrapContent.atMostWrapContent
width = Dimension.preferredValue(23.dp).atLeastWrapContent
width = Dimension.preferredValue(23.dp).atLeast(23.dp)
width = Dimension.preferredValue(23.dp)
width = Dimension.ratio("1:1")
width = Dimension.wrapContent
width = Dimension.percent(0.6f)
```

`preferredWrapContent`, `fillToConstraints`, `preferredValue(x.dp)`
will default to the *wrap*, *constrained*, or *filled* respectively.
but will enforce the additional constraints atLeast, etc.